# Facebook API : Now that post with link won't reach the feed, what would you do?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

here is the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/streamPublish/) state that

> Do not include an attachment or action link. If you do, the story will get published and will appear in the stream and on the user's Wall only. It won't appear at the top of the profile or in the Status Updates page.

Just wondering what others choose between

- still add a post with your link even it doesn't show in feed
- sending just a message and have it in feed?

Comment: That document refers to the old, deprecated FBJS … so I wonder if what it says there is even true any more.

Comment: I try adding post to user's wall from my site and the post does not show in the feed. When I remove link and send only message, it goes to feed. So I think it still apply